# Failing to inject Play's WSClient instance using injector

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I have a Class that has a WSClient dependancy injected:

```
@Singleton
class MyApiService @Inject() (wsclient: WSClient, conf: Configuration) {
...
}
```

and when running test and creating instance of MyApiService using injector :

```
class MyTest extends FreeSpec with OneAppPerSuite with ScalaFutures with WsScalaTestClient {

  implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer

  lazy val wsc: WSClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]
  lazy val conf: Configuration = app.injector.instanceOf[Configuration]

  val myApiService: MyApiService = app.injector.instanceOf[MyApiService]

  "Api Test" in {
    ...
  }
```

I get this error:

> > An exception or error caused a run to abort: Unable to provision, see
> >     the following errors:
> >
> > 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NumberFormatException:
> >     format error 10000   at
> >     play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider.(AhcWSModule.scala:40)
> >     at
> >     play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider.class(AhcWSModule.scala:39)
> >     while locating play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider   while
> >     locating play.shaded.ahc.org.  ...  Caused by:
> >     java.lang.NumberFormatException: format error 10000

and in my `application.cong` I added:

```
  ws.timeout.connection = 10000
  ws.timeout.idle = 10000
  ws.timeout.request = 10000
```

tried to change to 60000 theres no difference...

using play 2.6.0 and scala 2.11.8

someone maybe know why is it failing?

thanks

Comment: Did you solve your issue after all?

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem.  It is a formatting issue with the ws.timeout properties.

In Play 2.6, those properties are required to have a time unit.  Here is an [example configuration](https://github.com/playframework/play-ws/blob/master/play-ws-standalone/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L9)

WSConfigParser tries to construct an instance of scala.concurrent.Duration with the values from those properties.  Duration will [throw an exception](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/07d61ecf134dbba143531f5a1bd3c1289c437296/src/library/scala/concurrent/duration/Duration.scala#L65) if the values provided do not have a valid time unit.

The fix is to add `ms` to these properties -> `1000ms`

This is my application.conf

```
play {
  ws {
    timeout {
      connection: 10000ms
      idle: 30000ms
      request: 60000ms
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might relate to this issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7056#issuecomment-285370901

There is a suggested workaround:
create the file
/conf/ahc-default.properties with the contents of this gist https://gist.github.com/domdorn/3c80fac337ffc847650ae5f547f62c55

Comment: didnt help my friend...:/

Comment: are you running latest compatible versions of everything? - other than that Im out of suggestions - soz :)