# Failing to use play framework app injector to inject WSClient

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.6

Im using play 2.6.0 and scala 2.11.8

I was always using play's `WSClient` with no issues with the same configurations:

application.conf:

```
play {
  ws.timeout.connection = 600000
  ws.timeout.idle = 600000
  ws.timeout.request = 600000
}
```

and now I need to inject an instace of it in my test cauese one of my classes has it as a dependancy.

it looks like this:

```
class TestClass extends FreeSpec with OneAppPerSuite {


  implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer

  // this line is failing
  val ws: WSClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]

  ..
}
```

at this point the test already fails with this error:

> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   format error 600000   at
>   play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider.(AhcWSModule.scala:40)
>   at
>   play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider.class(AhcWSModule.scala:39)
>   while locating play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider   while
>   locating play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHttpClient
>       for the 1st parameter of play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientProvider.(AhcWSModule.scala:203)
>   at
>   play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientProvider.class(AhcWSModule.scala:203) 
>   while locating play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientProvider   while
>   locating play.api.libs.ws.WSClient

Caused by:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: format error 600000

does anyone have any idea why this is happening? didnt find anything that could help me online, i tried...

Comment: somebody recently asked the exact same  question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067001/failing-to-inject-plays-wsclient-instance-using-injector). yours would be a duplicate if that one had an answer

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and discovered it was not a duplicate of [this issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7056#issuecomment-285370901), but a property formatting error. As of Play 2.6, WS properties must be specified with both a value and unit (ie. 10000ms). So your properties would change to something more like the following:

```
play.ws.connection.timeout = 10000ms
```